# Can't Scroll Viewport up or down with finger over Chart

Tags: html, angularjs, chart.js

I have used `ChartJS` and `AngularJS` to make a doughnut and line chart on my mobile app . The problem that I am facing is that I can't scroll up or down the viewport/screen. If I try scrolling from beside the chart or from anywhere else on the screen but from over the chart, I can scroll up or down, just not from over the chart. Can someone please help me on how to fix this?